# CDI interceptor in extended class doesn't work when called form base class referance

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, interceptor, extends

I have problem with CDI interceptors. In my EJB module I create interceptor annotation, and its implementation, I also added implementation class to beans.xml. I have abstract class named AbstractFacade and some classes derived form it. In one class I override create method and add my interceptor annotation to it. Now in web module I have instance of ejb bean with interceptor annotation, but reference to it has AbstractFacade type. When I call create method on this reference apropriate metod in ejb module is called(this one with annotation) but my interceptor is not called, but if I cast this reference to its real type and call create interceptor will work properly. I'm not sure if I managed to describe it well, so here are the codes:

FooInter.java

```
package foo;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;

@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface FooInter{}
```

FooInterImpl.java

```
package foo;

import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

@Interceptor
@FooInter
public class FooInterImpl {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object fuckCall(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Interceptor: it works");

        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <class>foo.FooInterImpl</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

AbstractFacade.java

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    //...

    public void create(T entity) {
        //...
    }
}
```

FooFacade.java

```
@Stateless
public class FooFacade extends AbstractFacade<Foo> {

    //...

    @Override
    @FooInter
    public void create(Foo entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }
}
```

Ok, and this is in war:

EditHelper.java

```
public abstract class EditHelper<T> {
    protected T entity;

    //...

    protected abstract AbstractFacade<T> getFacade();

    public void save() {
        //...
        //if T is foo and getFacade returns FooFacade, interceptor won't be called here!
        getFacade().create(entity);
    }
}
```

FooEditHelper.java

```
public class FooEditHelper extends EditHelper<Foo> {
    @EJB
    private FooFacade fooFacade;

    //...

    protected AbstractFacade<T> getFacade() {
        return fooFacade;
    }

    @Override
    public void save() {
        getFacade().create(entity); //interceptor won't works !!!!!!!!!!!
        ((FooFacade)getFacade()).create(entity); //but here interceptor will work
    }
}
```

I don't have any idea why getFacade().create(entity); won't fire interceptor. I will be very glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be a bit off-topic, but I am in the process of migrating from JSF Managed beans to CDI managed beans, and I just confirmed that I am able to use [super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) successfully in a descendant CDI bean (with 'custom' @Descendant qualifier) that 'extends' an ancestor CDI bean (with @Default qualifier).

CDI bean ancestor with @Default qualifier:

```
@Default
@Named("pf_pointOfContactController")
@SessionScoped
public class pf_PointOfContactController implements Serializable {
```

Ancestor bean has the following:

```
@PostConstruct
protected void init() {
```

CDI bean descendant with @Descendant qualifier:

```
@Descendant
@Named("pf_orderCustomerPointOfContactController")
@SessionScoped
public class pf_OrderCustomerPointOfContactController extends pf_PointOfContactController {
```

Descendant bean has the following:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    super.init();
```

I had to add/use super.init(), because methods in the ancestor CDI bean were raising NullPointerException, since ancestor bean's @PostConstruct is not executed in CDI @Descendant bean.

I've seen/heard/read that it is recommended to use @PostConstruct instead of Constructor method when using CDI, so ancestor bean's constructor had the 'initialization' logic, and ancestor bean's constructor was automatically invoked/executed when using JSF managed beans.

Comment: The main difference here is the difference between super and this. if you don't specify super, you're using this, which isn't proxied.